# Software or Script to export decorative font glyph outlines to vector images

Tags: svg, software-recommendation, ttf

My friend had created some decor fonts for fun with his drawings long back. Now he is asking to extract outlines from ttf file format in any vector format. Fontforge does allow to export ttf as SVG font file. But I am clueless on how to make use of it. Is there any script or software or method to do this?

Comment: Type the glyph in any decent vector image editor (Illustrator, Inkscape, Affinity designer etc), and convert to outlines, and save/export as SVG.

Answer (score 1):

SVG can be parsed by Illustrator, Affinity Designer, Inkscape and other such vector art tools - it's then a trivial matter to switch the areas which are filled to carrying a stroke, and re-export those as `.svg` - or if you're comfortable with `.svg` code (it's human parseable so not hard) you can manually edit in any text editor if you've the time.